# matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks throws "set_ticks() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Tags: python, matplotlib

this easy example from matplotlib throws the mentioned error:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

I also cannot find any typo according to the documentation of set_xticks():

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html

Can anyone provide clearification and some help, please?

Kind regards, Daniel

Comment: I got the same error, but I think this is a mistake in the description, so please change it to the following. `ax.set_xticks(x);ax.set_xticklabels(labels)`

Comment: Great, this works, thank you very much! But where to report this mistake in the matplotlib documentation best?

Comment: This is not a mistake - you both are just using older matplotlib versions.  If you need access to older versions, you can change the url: https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html
https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: I did not know this. It looks like you just need to get the latest version.

Comment: A new feature in matplotlib 3.5.0 has been added to allow simultaneous use of ticks and tick names. See [https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.5.0.html#titles-ticks-and-labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.5.0.html#titles-ticks-and-labels) for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is error is based on the matplotlib version you use. The `set_axis` command was changed from matplotlib version 3.4.x to 3.5.x.
Try using the newer version. You can install it via

```
$ pip install matplotlib==3.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had forgotten to activate my Python virtual environment, so the interpreter was referencing an older version of matplotlib with no function named `set_xticks`.

Running `pipenv shell` before starting my script fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I still had this problem with matplotlib 3.7.1. It was resolved by naming the arguments:

```
cb.set_ticks(ticks=tick_list,labels=label_list)
```